# Run command on single file when changed with some shell magic (e.g replace extension)

Tags: macos, zsh, cross-platform, entr

I am writing several [.gv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) files ([graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/)) in the same directory and want to create a png file with `neato` immediately when I have saved one of them. I am on macOS 10.12.6, with `zsh` as my default shell, and I have installed `entr` from https://github.com/eradman/entr to monitor file changes. I have tried following command without any luck

```
$ echo $0
-zsh
$ ls *.gv | entr 'F="/_";neato -Tpng "$F" -o"${F/%\.gv/.png}"'
entr: exec F="/_";neato -Tpng "$F" -o"${F/%\.gv/.png}": No such file or directory
```

Following works

1. Simple printing of last modified file

   ```
    $ ls *.gv | entr echo /_
    # Press <Space> to manually trigger event to see last changed file
    /Users/hotschke/complete.gv
   ```
2. Using the same output name for all files:

   ```
    $ ls *.gv | entr neato -Tpng /_ -oConstantname.png
   ```
3. Replace .gv with .png

   ```
    $ F="/Users/hotschke/complete.gv";neato -Tpng "$F" -o"${F/%\.gv/.png}"
   ```

Note the special argument `/_` of `entr`

> The special `/_` argument (somewhat analogous to `$_` in Perl) provides a quick way to refer to the first file that changed. When a single file is listed this is a handy way to avoid typing a pathname twice:

It would be great to have several answers using different tools
(e.g. watchman, watchdog, fswatch, entr, launchd (mac-only); see also the discussion https://stackoverflow.com/q/1515730/)

Comment: Why not use `inotifywait -m`, which outputs touched nodes, rather than `entr` which appears to consume a list of nodes to monitor. You can then use `sed` (or similar) to produce a command to run.

Comment: I do not mind to use inotifywait. However, as far as I can see it does not exist on macOS.

Comment: I would prefer a cross-platform solution, but using only builtin utilities is as good as this.

Comment: Huh, you used the `inotify` tag...

Comment: Attie: Sorry for the misleading tag! I did not find a good one.

Comment: Have you seen [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch)?

Comment: @bertieb:  It is the final step when combining the 2. and 3. command: replacing the constant output file name with the one derived from `/_` by replacing the extension `gv` with `png`. I think, it is possibly an issue of shell escaping. Does my initially mentioned command work for you? I would be surprised.

Comment: @bertieb: I have also added the error message to the question.

Comment: @Hotschke Looks like we both got as far as the Bitbucket repo- would you like to add Eic's explanation as an answer? I'm happy to close the loop but figured you should get the first crack :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `Entr` – Pass `/_` as an argument to a shell

```
ls *.gv | entr bash -c 'neato -Tpng "$0" -o"${0/%\.gv/.png}"' /_
```

This answer is from https://bitbucket.org/eradman/entr/issues/75/run-command-on-single-file-when-changed#comment-44183153.

This command silently executes the command `neato`. If you want to have feedback on the command line when `entr` detects a file change, add `-x` to bash to see the executed command:

```
ls *.gv | entr bash -x -c 'neato -Tpng "$0" -o"${0/%\.gv/.png}"' /_
```

Answer (score 2):

## Call a script with `entr`

**tl;dr**: pass `/_` as an argument to a script to Do The Thing™

Rather than trying to futz with special arguments and variables, pass `/_` to a simple script (which itself can be a one liner) to do your png generation:

```
$  ls *.gv | entr ./update.sh /_
```

with `update.sh` along the lines of:

```
neato -Tpng "$1" -o"${1/%\.gv/.png}"
```

I tested the above approach with with a simple script to use imagemagick to `convert` an image, which worked without quotes, but it's better to leave them in in case of spaces etc in filenames.

As a side note, I tend to use an update script with `entr` anyway as it keeps things clearer to my mind. For example, I use `entr` to watch LaTeX source files and generate an updated PDF, the update script in that case runs `xelatex`, `biber` and also refreshes the PDF viewer (`pkill -HUP mupdf`).

Comment: Thanks! In this circumstance however, I would prefer avoiding to create a script. If I would create a support file for building, I would write a Makefile and use the suggested workflow `$ ls *.gv | entr make`. The Makefile would work without entr or similar and text editors often support calling a makefile (e.g. vim). I use vim and could activate an autocommand for the event of saving `:au BufWritePost <buffer> make`. If I want that make runs in the background, I can use vim-dispatch, asyncrun.vim, neomake, vim-accio or one of the many other plugins out there.

Comment: BTW, do you know [latexmk](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk)? It is part of TexLive. It offers the option `$ latexmk -pvc` which makes `entr` redundant and is very clever regarding calling the programs xelatex, biber and other just as often as needed and also refreshes the viewer.

Comment: @Hotschke fair point about makefiles (and good answer); I don't come from a programming background so it would be more work for me to learn their syntax -- on TODO list -- then write a one-to-three-ish liner depending on context; though I'll admit it feels a bit un-unixy to not use the right tool for the job.

Comment: IMHO Makefile syntax is not really intuitive. It took me a while to learn it and I still have to look up the meaning of `$<`, `$+` and similar. I do not use it often enough and also prefer latexmk for latex and cmake for c/c++.

Answer (score 1):

### Using `fswatch` instead of `entr`

Thanks to @Attie for pointing `fswatch` out. Following works for me:

```
 $ fswatch -e ".*" -i "$PWD/[^.]*\\.gv$" -0 $PWD |
     xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} sh -c 'F={}; neato -Tpng "$F" -o"${F/%\.gv/.png}"'
```

fswatch considers by default all files: you need to use filters to limit to a certain file type
(see https://stackoverflow.com/q/34713278/).

https://emcrisostomo.github.io/fswatch/ by Enrico M. Crisostomo (2013-2017)

Answer (score 1):

### Using a Makefile

```
SOURCES:=$(shell find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.gv')

ifndef OTYPE
    OTYPE:=png
endif
# use `make OTYPE=pdf` to generate pdfs

TARGETS:=$(SOURCES:.gv=.$(OTYPE))

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TARGETS)

clean:
    rm $(TARGETS)

%.$(OTYPE) : %.gv
    neato -T$(OTYPE) $< -o$(basename $<).$(OTYPE)
```

Now you can use

```
$ ls *.gv | entr make
```

There is room for improvement: there a two commands to list files with the extension .gv which contradicts a *single source of truth* (SSOT).

**Vim Notes**

You can also use the Makefile inside the text editor vim

```
:mak[e]
```

You can automatically call make on save by setting up an autocommand with

```
:au BufWritePost <buffer> make
```

You might consider to use a plugin for runnning make async: see the plugins [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) (normal mode mapping `m<CR>`), [neomake](https://github.com/neomake/neomake), or [asyncrun.vim](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim).

However, there are already compiler definitions for the commands dot and neato:

- https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/compiler/dot.vim
- https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/compiler/neato.vim

This means you do not need to write a Makefile.
You can set the makeprg by `:comp[iler] neato` or `:comp dot`. Note that you see all compiler definitions by `:comp <C-d>` and you can tab-complete `:comp n<Tab>` to `:comp neato` and `:comp d<tab>` to `:comp dot`.

Now you have to call make with an argument to specifiy your output format:

```
:make png
:au BufWritePost <buffer> make png
```

If you use vim-dispatch, this looks like

```
:Make png
m<Space>png<CR>
:au BufWritePost <buffer> Make png
```